# Filter Columns on string value with /

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, python-unicode

I have the following Dataframe and I would like to filter typePath on value : \Universe

```
       id   name            technicalName   dataType    path                            typePath    

0   c64041  Active Client   Active Client   Property    \Sales\Client\Active Client     \Universe\Concept\BusinessTerm  

1   c64042  Active Customer Active Customer Property    \Sales\Client\Active Customer    \Universe
```

However when I do it like this :

```
df2=df_Glossary.query("typePath == '\Universe'")
df2
```

I have the following error message :

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 13-14: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Someone has the solution to able me to filter on the value I have indicated

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `r` to convert the normal string to raw string. Also, you need to escape `\U` with `\\U`:

```
In [481]: df_Glossary.query(r'typePath == "\\Universe"')
Out[481]: 
       id             name    technicalName  dataType                           path   typePath
1  c64042  Active Customer  Active Customer  Property  \Sales\Client\Active Customer  \Universe
```

OR as pere @JANO's comment:

```
df_Glossary.query(r'typePath == r"\Universe"')
```

Comment: Your can also use a raw string in the query: `r"typePath == r'\Universe'"`.

Comment: @JANO Yes, that too. I included in the answer.